# Histogram of the length of words exercise hint?

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I'm learning C with "The C Programming Language" book, and I'm trying to solve exercise 1.13:

"Write a program to print a histogram of the lengths of words in its input. It is easy to
draw the histogram with the bars horizontal; a vertical orientation is more challenging."

I wrote the code, but when I press CTRL+Z (End-of-File), it shows all zeros instead of the length of words.

Could anyone give me a hint on where I'm going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* print a histogram of the length of words from input */
main()
{
    int c, i, wordn, space;
    int lengthn[20];

    wordn = space = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        lengthn[i] = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')
            if (space == 1) {
                ++wordn;
                space = 0;
                ++i;
            }
        if (c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n') {
            ++lengthn[i];
            space = 1;
        }
    }
    printf("Length: ");
    for (i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
        printf("%d   ", lengthn[i]);
    printf("\n        --------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Word:   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10   11   12   13   14   15\n");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `printf` statements to find out what your code is doing?  Or stepping it through with a debugger?

Comment: I think the problem is with the lengthn[i] array, it shows all zeros instead of the length of words. I just can't figure out what is the correct way to get it to show the length of the 1st, 2nd, 3rd word, etc...

Comment: It's probably a good idea to learn.  But it's not necessary; like I suggested, you can just sprinkle your code with `printf`s that print the current value of variables, etc., to give you an idea of whether things are being updated as you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(Because the OP is asking for hints, not the solution)**

So ... what does `i` equal after this loop?

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    lengthn[i] = 0;
```

And where do you use it next?

Comment: After this loop, all the values in the array are initialized to 0, if I'm correct. And then I use it next in the printf statement at the end to print the values in the array. So that would mean that it will print all zeros when I press CTRL-Z. But in the while loop, I wrote code for what should i variable do if c is space, tab or newline, or if c is not space. If c is space, jump to the next array. If c is not space, increase value in the array by one.

Comment: @BlueSky ... (Because you wanted hints) - `i` ... not your array. Read the questions I pose above again ;)

Comment: @BlueSky: Slightly bigger hint: What will `i` be when you first `++i` or `++lengthn[i]` inside the `while` loop?

Comment: @Brian Roach. You should of put that bold heading there earlier. Apologies. :)

Comment: No worries - I just tend to be overly sarcastic at times ;-P

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i)     
    lengthn[i] = 0;
```

The value of `i` after this loop will be `i=20`

so you must **initialize `i`** before while loop

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. I forgot to reset variable i.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a code for the vertical orientation.
I'm new to C, so may be the code is not good.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define MAX_WORDS 100
#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

int maxlength(int length[], char num_of_word);

int main()
{
    char c,i,j,state,num_of_word;
    int length[MAX_WORDS];
    /*initialize length[]*/
        for(i=0;i<MAX_WORDS;i++){
        length[i]=0;
        }
    /* find the length of each word */
    num_of_word=0;
    while(num_of_word<MAX_WORDS && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != 'a'){
        if(c != ' ' && c!= '\t' && c!= '\n'){
            state = IN;
            length[num_of_word]++;
        }else{
            if(state != OUT){
                state = OUT;
                num_of_word++;
            }
        }
    }
    /*   draw histogram            */
    for(i= maxlength(length[],num_of_word);i>0;i--){
        for(j=0;j<num_of_word;j++){
            if(length[j]<i){
                printf(" ");
            }else{
                printf("|");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    /* print name of each column*/
    for(i=0;i<num_of_word;i++){
        printf("%d",i+1);
    }

    _getch();
    return(0);
}
/*sub-function that find the longest word */
int maxlength(int length[], char num_of_word){
    int i, max;
    max = length[0];
    for(i=1;i<num_of_word;i++){
        if(max<length[i]){
            max = length[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before anything, here is the output from the original code, changing just one line:

```
#define MAXLEN 3
```

`100` is for sure a bit too large for testing.

```
t te tes test tests
^Z
  1 -   1  *
  2 -   1  *
  3 -   0
  4 -   0
  5 -   0
  6 -   0
  7 -   0
  8 -   0
  9 -   0
 10 -   0
 11 -   0
 12 -   0
 13 -   0
 14 -   0
 15 -   0
 16 -   0
 17 -   0
 18 -   0
 19 -   0
 20 - -858993460

Overflow: 2
```

And we see the first problems:

- Numbers do not match: 5 words on input, only 4 accounted for.
- Negative value for words of length `20`

There are some *one_off* errors.

> Here follows some hints of 3 of the errors and a complete alternative example, with source code, output and arguments.

#### PROBLEM: words with `MAXLEN` length are ignored

It is not clear if `MAXLEN` is inclusive or not, but it seems to be more natural to include words with length `MAXLEN` in the histogram. But these words should be counted anyway: in the histogram or in the `overflow` count:

```
            if (nc < MAXLEN)
               ++wlen[nc];
           else if (nc > MAXLEN)
               ++overflow;
```

it is excluded here, since there is no match for `==`

#### change 1

```
            if (nc <= MAXLEN)
                ++wlen[nc];
            else if (nc > MAXLEN)
                ++overflow;
```

and we get

```
t te tes test tests
^Z
  1 -   1  *
  2 -   1  *
  3 -   1  *
  4 -   0
...
 20 - -858993460

Overflow: 2
```

Now we have the 5 words accounted for.

#### change 2

The giant number in overflow is due to an error here

```
    for (i = 1; i < MAXHIST + 1; ++i)
    {
        printf("%3d - %3d  ", i, wlen[i]);
        for (j = wlen[i]; j > MINLEN && j < MAXLEN; --j)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

since in the `printf` the index will go until `MAXHIST` but `wlen` goes from `0` to `MAXHIST-1`.

There are many ways to correct this. This is a simple one used here: just add 1 item to `wlen` array.

```
    int wlen[1+MAXHIST];
```

and use

```
    for (i = 1; i <= MAXHIST; ++i) wlen[i] = 0;
```

and we get

```
t te tes test tests
^Z
  1 -   1  *
  2 -   1  *
  3 -   1  *
  4 -   0
 ...
 20 -   0

Overflow: 2
```

### more about the code

The provided code is based on a book (K&R *bible*) from 1978. Since then many things changed. The [C-Faq](https://c-faq.com/) for example is often cited as reference guidelines for `C` programming, and dates back from the most part from the 90's. And was never updated since 2005...

But `C` language and concepts in programming have been changing since then. A lot.

#### 1

```
    nc = overflow = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < MAXHIST; ++i) wlen[i] = 0;
```

- Since decades we can and should declare `i` inside the `for`. In `C++` for example we can declare variables in `switch` or `while` or `if` header. It is important to reduce the scope --- lifetime --- of any variable, and specially those with naive names like `i` and `j`.
- multiple initialization is fancy but it makes harder to find variables inside it.

We can write just

```
    int nc                = 0;
    int overflow          = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXHIST; ++i) wlen[i] = 0;
```

Also we can write

```
    int wlen[1 + MAXHIST] = {0};
```

and delete this `for` loop, since the program runs just once with the array.

Instead of

```
    int state;
    state = OUT;
```

You should use

```
    int state = OUT;
```

- A function should print the histogram, something like

```
int print_h(unsigned len, int wlen[], unsigned overflow)
{
  for (unsigned i = 1; i <= len; ++i)
  {
      printf("%3d - %3d  ", i, wlen[i]);
      for (unsigned j = wlen[i]; j > MINLEN && j < MAXLEN;
           --j)
          printf("*");
      printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\nOverflow: %d\n", overflow);
  return 0;
}
```

will do ok. But the second loop just for printing the `*` is redundant.

#### the program now with these changes

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Prints a histogram of the lengths of words. */

#define MAXHIST 20
#define MAXLEN 3
#define MINLEN 0
#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

int print_h(unsigned len, int wlen[], unsigned overflow);

int main()
{
    int wlen[1 + MAXHIST] = {0};
    int nc                = 0;
    int overflow          = 0;

    int c     = 0;
    int state = OUT;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\t' || c == '\n' || c == ' ')
        {
            state = OUT;
            if (nc <= MAXLEN)
                ++wlen[nc];
            else if (nc > MAXLEN)
                ++overflow;
        }
        else if (state == OUT)
        {
            state = IN;
            nc    = 1;
        }
        else { ++nc; }
    }
    print_h(MAXHIST, wlen, overflow);
    return 0;
}

int print_h(unsigned len, int wlen[], unsigned overflow)
{
    for (unsigned i = 1; i <= len; ++i)
    {
        printf("%3d - %3d  ", i, wlen[i]);
        for (unsigned j = wlen[i]; j > MINLEN && j < MAXLEN;
             --j)
            printf("*");
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\nOverflow: %d\n", overflow);
    return 0;
}
```

#### sample output

```
t te test tests
^Z
  1 -   1  *
  2 -   1  *
  3 -   0
  4 -   0
  5 -   0
  6 -   0
  7 -   0
  8 -   0
  9 -   0
 10 -   0
 11 -   0
 12 -   0
 13 -   0
 14 -   0
 15 -   0
 16 -   0
 17 -   0
 18 -   0
 19 -   0
 20 -   0

Overflow: 2
```

#### about the state machine and another possible problem

- using an `if` to control the states, and testing first the stream of letters and then the states is very hard to follow. In general Finite State Machines are filters of some input (a stream of letters in this case) that are fed in a loop, then a `switch` gets the `state` and does its thing.
- FSM states must be tested before the item (the letter in this case. The idea is that each state is independent and could be coded separately, even by diferent people and time.
- **overflow** should be a state: when a word reaches the overflow count then all remaining letters are skipped. This is a different behavior and it is easier to code it this way.
- **EOF** should be a state also: at `EOF` we just print the results and terminate.

  - **But at EOF we may have a word being scanned and the way the provided code works it will be ignored.**

### an alternative example

Instead of changing the provided code step by step I will leave here a complete `C` example, sample output  and some arguments, in order to not have an even larger post.

#### Some results from the example

```
Stack Overflow C>_ p
    maximum word len is 4 (inclusive)
test
^Z
  1 -   0
  2 -   0
  3 -   0
  4 -   1  *
  5 -   0
  6 -   0
  7 -   0
  8 -   0
  9 -   0
 10 -   0
 11 -   0
 12 -   0
 13 -   0
 14 -   0
 15 -   0
 16 -   0
 17 -   0
 18 -   0
 19 -   0
 20 -   0

1 words in histogram [overflow: 0 words]. [All words accounted for].


Stack Overflow C>_ echo t te tes test tests | p
    maximum word len is 4 (inclusive)
  1 -   1  *
  2 -   1  *
  3 -   1  *
  4 -   1  *
  5 -   0
  6 -   0
...
 20 -   0

4 words in histogram [overflow: 1 words]. [All words accounted for].

Stack Overflow C>_ p 5
    maximum word len is 5 (inclusive)
1 12 123 1234
^Z
  1 -   1  *
  2 -   1  *
  3 -   1  *
  4 -   1  *
  5 -   0
  6 -   0
...
 20 -   0

4 words in histogram [overflow: 0 words]. [All words accounted for].

Stack Overflow C>_ echo t | p 5
    maximum word len is 5 (inclusive)
  1 -   1  *
  2 -   0
  3 -   0
 ...
 20 -   0

1 words in histogram [overflow: 0 words]. [All words accounted for].

Stack Overflow C>_ echo t te tes test tests | p 4
    maximum word len is 4 (inclusive)
  1 -   1  *
  2 -   1  *
  3 -   1  *
  4 -   1  *
  5 -   0
...
 20 -   0

4 words in histogram [overflow: 1 words]. [All words accounted for].


Stack Overflow C>_
```

- The program `p` assumes a default length of 4 letters, but the user can provide the value on the command line as in `p 12` for a maximum of 12 letter words.

  - a line like `echo t te tes test tests | p 4` on the terminal runs the program using 4 as the maximum length and the text between `echo` and the pipe `|` sign as input, so it makes testing faster and easier.
  - the code keeps a count of words read. At the end compares it to the sum of words in the histogram plus the overflow count, and reports an eventual mismatch.

#### Complete code for the example

```
/* Prints a histogram of the lengths of words. */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXHIST 20
#define MAXLEN 4
#define MINLEN 0

// states for the FSM
#define S_OUT 0
#define S_IN 1
#define S_OVERFLOW 2
#define S_EOF 3

// delimiters for wor
#define TAB '\t'
#define NEWLINE '\n'
#define SPACE ' '

int print_h(
    unsigned len, int wlen[], unsigned overflow,
    unsigned n_words);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    unsigned max_l = MAXLEN;  // default
    if (argc > 1) max_l = atoi(argv[1]);
    fprintf(
        stderr, "    maximum word len is %u (inclusive)\n",
        max_l);

    int      wlen[1 + MAXHIST] = {0};
    unsigned nc                = 0;
    unsigned n_words           = 0;
    unsigned overflow          = 0;

    int state = S_OUT;

    int c = getchar();  // read first char
    do {
        switch (state)
        {
            case S_OUT:
                switch (c)
                {
                    case SPACE:
                    case TAB:
                    case NEWLINE:
                        // keep searching
                        c = getchar();  // keep going
                        break;
                    case EOF:
                        state = S_EOF;
                        // just go
                        break;
                    default:
                        // some non-space char
                        state = S_IN;
                        nc    = 1;
                        c     = getchar();  // keep going
                        break;
                };  // switc
                break;

            case S_IN:  // in a word
                switch (c)
                {
                    case SPACE:
                    case TAB:
                    case NEWLINE:  // white-space
                        ++wlen[nc];
                        ++n_words;
                        state = S_OUT;
                        c     = getchar();  // keep going
                        break;
                    case EOF:
                        if (nc <= max_l) ++wlen[nc]; // last word
                        ++n_words;
                        state = S_EOF;
                        break;
                    default:  // another non-space char
                        nc += 1;
                        c = getchar();  // keep going
                        if (nc > max_l)
                        {
                            overflow += 1;
                            ++n_words;
                            state = S_OVERFLOW;
                            break;
                        }
                        break;
                };              // switch
                break;

            case S_OVERFLOW:
                switch (c)
                {
                    case SPACE:
                    case TAB:
                    case NEWLINE:       // white-space
                        state = S_OUT;  // back to search
                        c     = getchar();  // keep going
                        break;
                    case EOF:  // we have a last word to
                               // account for
                        state = S_EOF;
                        break;
                    default:  // another non-space char
                        // do nothing
                        c = getchar();  // keep going
                        break;
                };              // switch
                break;

            case S_EOF:  // print results and return
            default:
                print_h(MAXHIST, wlen, overflow, n_words);
                return 0;
                break;

        };  // switch(state)

    } while (1);  // while

    return 0;  // to make the compiler happy
};             // main





int print_h(
    unsigned len, int wlen[], unsigned overflow,
    unsigned n_words)
{
    long unsigned n_hist = 0;  // words on table
    for (unsigned i = 1; i <= len; ++i)
    {
        printf("%3d - %3d  ", i, wlen[i]);
        n_hist += wlen[i];
        if (wlen[i] > 0)
            printf("*\n");
        else
            printf("\n");
    }
    printf(
        "\n%lu words in histogram [overflow: %d words].",
        n_hist, overflow);
    long unsigned total = n_hist + overflow;
    if (n_words == total)
        printf(" [All words accounted for].\n");
    else
        printf(
            "\
\n\
[ERROR]: %lu words in histogram\n\
         %u words on overflow\n\
         %u words on input.\n",
            n_hist, overflow, n_words);
    return 0;
}
```

#### about the example code

- there are 4 states: overflow and eof were added
- accepts a max len from the command line
- test the states in an infinite loop

As an example, here is code for the `S_IN` state, when we are inside a word, with a new `c` value just read:

```
           case S_IN:  // in a word
               switch (c)
               {
                   case SPACE:
                   case TAB:
                   case NEWLINE:  // white-space
                       ++wlen[nc];
                       ++n_words;
                       state = S_OUT;
                       c     = getchar();  // keep going
                       break;
                   case EOF:
                       if (nc <= max_l) ++wlen[nc]; // last word
                       ++n_words;
                       state = S_EOF;
                       break;
                   default:  // another non-space char
                       nc += 1;
                       c = getchar();  // keep going
                       if (nc > max_l)
                       {
                           overflow += 1;
                           ++n_words;
                           state = S_OVERFLOW;
                           break;
                       }
                       break;
               };              // switch
               break;
```

All states use similar code:  a switch on the letter, so it is faster to write and manage states. Above we see the transitions to the other 3 states.
The code for `S_OVERFLOW` is similar:

```
            case S_OVERFLOW:
                switch (c)
                {
                    case SPACE:
                    case TAB:
                    case NEWLINE:       // white-space
                        state = S_OUT;  // back to search
                        c     = getchar();  // keep going
                        break;
                    case EOF:  // we have a last word to
                               // account for
                        state = S_EOF;
                        break;
                    default:  // another non-space char
                        // do nothing
                        c = getchar();  // keep going
                        break;
                };              // switch
                break;
```

And this what I am trying to show. The logic of overflow is not buried inside `S_IN` and there is no tests there for skipping remaining letters. A FSM makes it easier to abstract a model.

The code for each state can be developed and tested by different people.